# android studio import eclipse project

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-studio

I am using android studio 1.0.2
for a month
and when I import aproject I am asked to choose project folder
and after clicking ok I am redirected to a window asking project destination
and from there it strait forword to finish importing

now I am encounter a different wizard 
after selecting project folder I am getting to
a window asking me to choose import gradle from external model
and dont alow me to check the use gradle wrapper(grayed out)

so at the end I  get my project imported without any gradle
files

hope somone can help know why did it changed
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer
I did not point to the project directory that 
I wanted to import to android studio
that is containing the project files 
(I choose directory that contained that directory and that cause the difficulty)

thanks